# Error when printing PDF file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, reportviewer

I am trying to print a PDF file generated through reportViewer in my Web API, but the browser shows an error when tries to open the PDF file.

This is the code inside the controller in my **Web API**:

```
 // ...generate candidatosDataSet
 LocalReport relatorio = new LocalReport();
 string rootPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
 relatorio.ReportPath = rootPath + @"\Reports\Report.rdlc";


 relatorio.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Candidatos", candidatosDataSet));

 relatorio.Refresh();

 byte[] relatorioBytes = ExportUtils.GerarArquivoPDF(relatorio);


 response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, relatorioBytes);

 response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse("attachment; filename=relatorio.pdf");
 response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
```

This is how I am generating PDF File through **reportViewer**

```
 public static byte[] GerarArquivoPDF(LocalReport relatorio)
        {
            String reportType = "PDF";
            String mimeType;
            String encoding;
            String fileNameExtension;
            String deviceInfo;
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streams;
            byte[] renderedBytes;

            deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" + "  <OutputFormat>" + reportType + "</OutputFormat>" + "</DeviceInfo>";

            renderedBytes = relatorio.Render(
            reportType,
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);

            return renderedBytes;
        }
```

Here is my **AngularJS service** method:

```
function obterTermoConfirmacaoCandidatura(candidatoId) {
            return $http.get(configValues.baseUrl + 'candidato/GetRelatorio', 
            { 
                params: { candidatoId: candidatoId },
                responseType: 'arraybuffer'
            });
        }
```

And this is the code that I am using to print the file on the **AngularJS controller**:

```
function imprimirTermoConfirmacaoCandidatura(id) {
            CandidatoAPIService.obterTermoConfirmacaoCandidatura(id)
            .then(function (response) {

                var contentType = response.headers('Content-Type') || "application/octet-stream";

                var file = new Blob([response.data], {
                    type: contentType
                });

                var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                var printWindow = $window.open(fileUrl);
                printWindow.print();

            }, function (error) {
                alert(error.data);
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from Web API was comming as string, with double quotes in beginning and in the end of the response, so the PDF File could not be rendered correctly. Also I converted the response from server to base64, by this method:

```
 function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType) {

            var sliceSize = 512;
            b64Data = b64Data.replace(/"/g, '');
            b64Data = b64Data.replace(/^[^,]+,/, '');
            b64Data = b64Data.replace(/\s/g, '');

            var byteCharacters = window.atob(b64Data);
            var byteArrays = [];

            for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
                var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

                var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                    byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
                }

                var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

                byteArrays.push(byteArray);
            }

            var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
            return blob;
        }
```

And changed the method on **AngularJS controller** to convert the response do base64:

```
function imprimirTermoAutorizacaoUsoImagem() {
            CandidatoAPIService.obterTermoAutorizacaoUsoImagem()
            .then(function (response) {
                var contentType = response.headers('Content-Type') || "application/octet-stream";
                var file = UtilsService.b64toBlob(response.data, "application/pdf");

                var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                var printWindow = $window.open(fileUrl);
                printWindow.print();
            }, function (error) {
                alert(error.data);
            });
        }
```

And removed the `responseType` on the **AngularJS service**:

```
function obterTermoConfirmacaoCandidatura(candidatoId) {
            return $http.get(configValues.baseUrl + 'candidato/GetObterTermoConfirmacaoCandidatura', 
            {   
                params: { candidatoId: candidatoId }
            });
        }
```